# ruby Analyze a page to get infomation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to implement a function which is similar to interface. When i put a url as a parameter, i could use this api to get page form's all contents.

For example, there is a login page:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<label for="user_login">Login:</label>
<input class="registration-field" id="user_account" name="user[account]" size="30" type="text" />
<label for="user_password">Password:</label>
<input class="registration-field" id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" /></form>
```

Then how could I get the elements value, and put them to a mapping as the key-value module.
This is just a example, I couldn't know how many elements in this form.

Have anyone a suggetion ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre talking about scraping the page. You will need to use Nokogiri which is an HTML, XML and SAX parser

http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: Could you introduce the details for this question?

Comment: Look up this railcast:    http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri

Comment: sorry, i just know Nokogiri::HTML could get the html element because i just learn ruby servel days. The doc.css method is used page css, but when there is no css, how could I get form element?

Comment: but you do have css in the html mentioned above, for instance, if you apply railcasts logic to above value of user_account field is doc.at_css('#user_account').value. Please google for more Nokogiri information. You will need to read up on basics of parsing or just look at some scraping tutorials

Comment: thanks. I have google one day for this question. More is as you said.